# Replace ceiling fan speed selector to dimmer

Tags: capacitor, wiring, fans

I need to replace the 3-speed switch of my ceiling fan with a dimmer because the speed selector is broken and, for some reason, is much more expensive than the dimmer. I have this schematic where I represent the two systems (1 for the speed selector and 2 for the dimmer system).

[image]

My problem is that to use the dimmer I need to connect it to the max fan speed, which depends on the capacitor value. In my case, I have a 3 wires capacitor of 2 and 4 millifarad values, but my tester doesn't have a capacitance, so I use a continuity test to see how the speed selector works, which basically switches the line between capacitor wires. Now I can't understand how this works after that and how this configures my capacitor value to obtain the max speed.
As far as I know, connecting the capacitor in series will give 6millifarad and that will give the maximum speed with that capacitor, but I'm not sure if the speed selector works in that way and I'm afraid of burning the fan.

the dimmer looks like this:

[image]
[image]

Comment: How much does the correct replacement cost vs how much time you'll likely spend trying to get something (that probably won't work) operational. How much do you value your time? How big a risk are you willing to take with it? Personally speaking, I don't think it will work.

Comment: @Andyaka, $250 vs $30, its enough for me.

Comment: I have advised you that a dimmer won't work. Engineering (that's what this site is about) must account for the buy or build scenario. It's a buy scenario for me and that's my advice.

Comment: Well... I miss a fan winding wire connection in my diagram to the dimmer, but this dimmer is designed for ceiling fan wall control.

Comment: _”capacitor in series will give 6mf”_ Please clarify. 6 millifarad?

Comment: @winny, yes millifarad, I edit the postt. thank u

Comment: *but this dimmer is designed for ceiling fan wall control* Really? Does it actually say anything about motor/fan control? Or is rated *for the **light** part of a fan/light combination*?

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact, it also have a light, and fan switch separated of the dimmer

Comment: What make and model is your existing ceiling fan?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dimmer or Variable speed controller

Not the same thing.

Dimmer is a switch, it only switches power on/off at certain speed (delay). In doing so it does not consumes power it self. Not in our age, we use semiconductor devices for that. In old days there were variable resistors, that did consume power.

It switches on/off at about 120 times per second, with controllable delay when to switch.

light dimmer would not affect the speed of the motor because the motor’s speed is directly dependant off the frequency of the supply,

dimmer doesn’t affect the frequency; it affects the amount of energy available from each sine wave half-cycle of the mains power. (timed on/off)

**The Variable motor speed controller, controls the frequency.**

Motors work (rotate) by supplied frequency. So if you change the frequency you can slow down or speed up motor.

Example: Your standard frequency is 60 Hz. If you reduce it to 30 Hz the motor will slow down.

That is why the Motor controllers are more expensive.

That is why you should not use dimmer switch to control the motor.

Comment: +1 for "not the same thing"

Answer (score 3):

Conceptually, a dimmer and a motor speed control do the same thing: Reduce the amount of power used and the level of the output (how bright is the light/how fast is the motor).

But practically speaking, they go about their tasks in entirely different ways. On top of that, dimmers have actually changed in recent years in order to better work with LED lighting, and those changes don't improve the motor situation.

In a best case scenario, a dimmer will work with a motor but waste power. In a worst case scenario, the dimmer will effectively destroy the motor.

Non-dimmer switches (on/off, but possibly including timer, motion sensor, etc.) will include ratings that vary based on light type (LED, incandescent, CFL, with rating in Watts) or motor (rating in Amps, Watts or HP). Dimmer switches, at least all that I have seen, will *only* include rating for various types of lighting (and not all dimmers will work with all types of lighting) with *no* motor control capability.

Similarly, a motor speed control will work marginally, if at all, with modern lighting.

$250 does sound like a *lot* for a 3-speed fan control. For example, [Home Depot has the Lutron Maestro Fan Control and Light Dimmer](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Lutron-Maestro-Fan-Control-and-Light-Dimmer-for-dimmable-LEDs-Incandescent-and-Halogen-Bulbs-Single-Pole-White-MACL-LFQH-WH/303169873):

[image: Lutron Fan/Light]

which is rated at 75W LED or CFL, 250W incandescent and a 4-speed fan control up to 1.5A, all in one device for well under $100.

I don't know if this particular control is compatible with your fan/light, but this is the type of thing you should be looking for, not trying to make a *lighting* dimmer work as a *motor* control.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. On the speed control, #1 is the maximum speed. I bypassed it so now the fan is at maximum speed. Then I replaced the wall switch with a 4 speed controller to the fan. It works perfectly with no problems. Cost of the new wall controller about $20 at amazon.com.